# pseudo Anova Table for a GLS regression

Tags: r, generalized-least-squares, lme4-nlme

I fit a couple of GLS models, using the `nlme` pakage (`gls()` function), and I would like to obtain the pseudo ANOVA table as described by [Griffis & Stedinger (2007)](http://www.ltrr.arizona.edu/~katie/kt/FLOODS-USGS/GLS-Griffis-Stedinger.pdf). `nlme` doesn't calculate the pseudo Anova table. Despite I can understand the method described by Griffs and Stedinger, I am unable to program this. I am wondering if there is any R package that allows obtain this table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the definition of "pseudo ANOVA table" is but you can obtain a comprehensive ANOVA for a `gls` fit in R using:

```
require(rms)
f <- Gls(....)
anova(f)
```

Comment: Griffis & Stedinger (2007) use the term pseudo, because the way how calculate the sum of squares is not the traditional one as that used in OLS.

Comment: It would be interesting to compare that with the simpler Wald partial $\chi^2$ test approach that most people use.